# Best way to read data from text files stored in your app

Tags: ios, database, swift, core-data

What would be the best way to save large amounts of data within an app which the user can search through and display?

My thoughts are that I can have the files as supporting ".txt" files within my app, and the first time the app runs on the users phone, they'll load into core data and then be accessed by the user

Regarding this, I have two questions:

- How can I read from a supporting ".txt" file which is not directly in the apps file-system?
- I know how to save items into core-data, but is there anything I should consider when saving such large amounts of data? Methods for doing this, or other concerns?

If you have any other way of doing this efficiently it would be nice to know. Other than that, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to store?

Comment: @Subash Weather-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can of course read a text file into memory even if it is stored in the bundle of the application. You only need to copy a file into the application's documents directory if you want to write to it.

Second, a text file with, say, tab delimited data would be quite easy to parse and insert into Core Data. I think the most feasible way is to write it yourself with a few for loops.

Third, you are correct that this can take some time with large data sets. There are a couple of tricks to optimize the core data insertion; the most important one is that you determine a good *batch size* (usually 500-1000 records) and call `save` repeatedly after processing so many records.

Fourth, I would recommend that you do this conversion into Core Data *before* you distribute your app. After it finishes successfully, locate the generated sqlite file and *include that file* in your app bundle rather than the text file. On first run, copy the file to the documents directory as the file holding the Core Data persistent store. Just copying the file will be very fast and not disrupt the user experience upon first running your app.